# Maximum occurrence of any event in time range

Tags: java, algorithm

I have collection time stamps, e.g `10:18:07.490,11:50:18.251` where first is the start time and second is end time for an event. I need to find a range where maximum events are happening just 24 hours of time. These events are happening in precision of milliseconds.

What I am doing is to divide 24 hours on millisecond scale, and attach events at every millisecond, and then finding a range where maximum events are happening.

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse("00:00");
LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse("23:59");
```

```
for (LocalTime x = start; x.isBefore(end); x = x.plus(Duration.ofMillis(1))) {
        for (int i = 0; i < startTime.size(); i++) {
        if (startTime.get(i).isAfter(x) && endTime.get(i).isBefore(x))
            // add them to list;
        }

    }
```

Certainly this is not a good approach, it takes too much memory. How I can do it in a proper way? Any suggestion?

Comment: Why is 4GB less memory for such calculation. There are 8.64e7 elements only.

Comment: Why do you add them to the list?

Comment: your condition start > x and end < x can't be satisfied, because in your loop x is bigger than start

Answer (score 5):

#### A solution finding the first period of maximum concurrent events:

If you're willing to use a third party library, this can be implemented "relatively easy" in a SQL style with [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL)'s window functions. The idea is the same as explained in [amit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36119706/521799):

```
System.out.println(
    Seq.of(tuple(LocalTime.parse("10:18:07.490"), LocalTime.parse("11:50:18.251")),
           tuple(LocalTime.parse("09:37:03.100"), LocalTime.parse("16:57:13.938")),
           tuple(LocalTime.parse("08:15:11.201"), LocalTime.parse("10:33:17.019")),
           tuple(LocalTime.parse("10:37:03.100"), LocalTime.parse("11:00:15.123")),
           tuple(LocalTime.parse("11:20:55.037"), LocalTime.parse("14:37:25.188")),
           tuple(LocalTime.parse("12:15:00.000"), LocalTime.parse("14:13:11.456")))
       .flatMap(t -> Seq.of(tuple(t.v1, 1), tuple(t.v2, -1)))
       .sorted(Comparator.comparing(t -> t.v1))
       .window(Long.MIN_VALUE, 0)
       .map(w -> tuple(
           w.value().v1,
           w.lead().map(t -> t.v1).orElse(null),
           w.sum(t -> t.v2).orElse(0)))
       .maxBy(t -> t.v3)
);
```

The above prints:

```
Optional[(10:18:07.490, 10:33:17.019, 3)]
```

So, during the period between 10:18... and 10:33..., there had been 3 events, which is the most number of events that overlap at any time during the day.

#### Finding all periods of maximum concurrent events:

Note that there are several periods when there are 3 concurrent events in the sample data. `maxBy()` returns only the first such period. In order to return all such periods, use `maxAllBy()` instead (added to jOOλ 0.9.11):

```
   .maxAllBy(t -> t.v3)
   .toList()
```

Yielding then:

```
[(10:18:07.490, 10:33:17.019, 3), 
 (10:37:03.100, 11:00:15.123, 3), 
 (11:20:55.037, 11:50:18.251, 3), 
 (12:15       , 14:13:11.456, 3)]
```

#### Or, a graphical representation

```
3                  /-----\       /-----\       /-----\       /-----\
2           /-----/       \-----/       \-----/       \-----/       \-----\
1     -----/                                                               \-----\
0                                                                                 \--
   08:15  09:37  10:18  10:33  10:37  11:00  11:20  11:50  12:15  14:13  14:37  16:57
```

#### Explanations:

Here's the original solution again with comments:

```
// This is your input data    
Seq.of(tuple(LocalTime.parse("10:18:07.490"), LocalTime.parse("11:50:18.251")),
       tuple(LocalTime.parse("09:37:03.100"), LocalTime.parse("16:57:13.938")),
       tuple(LocalTime.parse("08:15:11.201"), LocalTime.parse("10:33:17.019")),
       tuple(LocalTime.parse("10:37:03.100"), LocalTime.parse("11:00:15.123")),
       tuple(LocalTime.parse("11:20:55.037"), LocalTime.parse("14:37:25.188")),
       tuple(LocalTime.parse("12:15:00.000"), LocalTime.parse("14:13:11.456")))

   // Flatten "start" and "end" times into a single sequence, with start times being
   // accompanied by a "+1" event, and end times by a "-1" event, which can then be summed
   .flatMap(t -> Seq.of(tuple(t.v1, 1), tuple(t.v2, -1)))

   // Sort the "start" and "end" times according to the time
   .sorted(Comparator.comparing(t -> t.v1))

   // Create a "window" between the first time and the current time in the sequence
   .window(Long.MIN_VALUE, 0)

   // Map each time value to a tuple containing
   // (1) the time value itself
   // (2) the subsequent time value (lead)
   // (3) the "running total" of the +1 / -1 values
   .map(w -> tuple(
       w.value().v1,
       w.lead().map(t -> t.v1).orElse(null),
       w.sum(t -> t.v2).orElse(0)))

   // Now, find the tuple that has the maximum "running total" value
   .maxBy(t -> t.v3)
```

I have written up more about [window functions and how to implement them in Java in this blog post](http://blog.jooq.org/2016/01/06/2016-will-be-the-year-remembered-as-when-java-finally-had-window-functions/).

(disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOλ)

Answer (score 3):

It can be done significantly better in terms of memory (well, assuming O(n) is considered good for you, and you don't regard 24*60*60*1000 as tolerable constant):

- Create a list of items `[time, type]` (where time is the time, and type is
  either start or end).
- Sort the list by time.
- Iterate the list, and when you see a "start", increment a counter, and when you see a "end", decrememnt it.

By storing a "so far seen maximum", you can easily identify the single point where maximal number of events occuring on it.

If you want to get the interval containing this point, you can simply find the time where "first maximum" occures, until when it ends (which is the next `[time, type]` pair, or if you allow start,end to be together and not counted, just linear scan from this point until the counter decreases and time moved, this can be done only once, and does not change total complexity of the algorithm). 

This is really easy to modify this approach to get the interval from the point

Comment: As OP said, he needs the time range. Quoting: `"finding a range where maximum events are happening"`

Comment: @vish4071 So, get the time interval between "first maximum" occures, until when it ends (which is the next [time, type] pair, or if you allow start,end to be together and not counted, just linear scan from this point until the counter decreases and time moved, this can be done only once, and does not change total complexity of the algorithm). This is really easy to modify this approach to get the interval from the point.

Comment: I'm curious to see an actual algorithm that performs in `O(N)`. It appears that this solution requires sorting of the event stream to work, so `O(N log N)` complexity seems inevitable.

Comment: @LukasEder If you really need O(N), you can represent the tuples as integers and use a radix sort for the sorting step.  In any case, this is the best answer.

Comment: @LukasEder It cannot be done in "strict" `O(n)` on algebraic tree model, because it is variant of [Element Distincntess Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem).

Comment: @MattTimmermans: This wasn't about best answers ;) This was me curious about `O(N)`. I forgot about radix sort, which certainly makes sense with timestamps for large `N`. Good point.

Comment: Yes @amit, I totally agree wiith your point there. I just wanted you to improve (edit) your answer with that added

Comment: @vish4071 here you go.